# shared-ptr and error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed - C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Compiler has pointed ,among other mistakes, at strings(emphasized). Have i used the **shared_ptr** s' wrong? Is compiler able to get in **private** with purpose of setting the value, by this non-explicit way?

## stack_class.h

```
#pragma once  //(i've tried also without this)
#include <memory>
class Stack
{
private:
    shared_ptr<int> n; // this string 
public:
        Stack();
};
```

### stack_class.cpp

```
//#include's
using namespace std;
Stack::Stack()
{
    shared_ptr<int> n_user(new int);
    cin >> *n_user;
    shared_ptr<int> n(new int);
    this->n = n_user;
}
```

Comment: `#include <memory>` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Please post the complete error message, also make sure your code is a [MCVE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header file needs to look like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory> // ADDED
class Stack
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> n; // ADDED std:: 
    int *s_array;
    std::shared_ptr<int> amount; // ADDED std::
public:
    Stack();
    void Push(int value);
    int Get(int receiver);
    ~Stack();
};
```

Comment: @user2952487 you use "using namespace std" in your cpp file, but not in your header (neither before including the header).

Comment: @user2952487: You must not say `using namespace` at the top level of a header file.  The way I wrote it is correct.

Comment: juanchopanza, your prattle hadn't helped me. PeterT and John Zwinck have helped.